# geom_smooth does not draw regression line when some color groups do not have enough points

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the degree of 2, for example, if I run:

```r
set.seed(42)
tbl <- data.frame(x=trunc(100*runif(100)), y=trunc(100*runif(100)), color=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 40), rep("C", 9), rep("D", 1)))
tbl %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = color) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1L, size = 5L, shape = "circle") +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 2),
    se = TRUE,
    level = 0.95,
    method = "lm"
  )
```

the output plot will contain 3 trend lines, for the groups `A`, `B`, and `C`. It does not draw a line for the group `D` because it only has 1 point, which is not enough to fit line with degree two.

This is correct behavior.

However, If I increase the polynomial degree to 9:

```r
set.seed(42)
tbl <- data.frame(x=trunc(100*runif(100)), y=trunc(100*runif(100)), color=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 40), rep("C", 9), rep("D", 1)))
tbl %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = color) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1L, size = 5L, shape = "circle") +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 9),
    se = TRUE,
    level = 0.95,
    method = "lm"
  )
```

I get a scatterplot with no lines drawn.

But, the group `A` for example, does contain enough points to fit a line with degree 9:

```r
set.seed(42)
tbl <- data.frame(x=trunc(100*runif(100)), y=trunc(100*runif(100)), color=c(rep("A", 50), rep("B", 40), rep("C", 9), rep("D", 1)))
tbl[tbl$color == "A", ] %>% ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = color) +
  geom_point(alpha = 1L, size = 5L, shape = "circle") +
  geom_smooth(
    formula = y ~ poly(x, 9),
    se = TRUE,
    level = 0.95,
    method = "lm"
  )
```

you will get a scatter plot with fitted line.

Thus, in the second code chunk, why is no line drawn? Shouldn't a line be drawn for the group `A` at minimum?

R version is: 3.6.3
ggplot2 version is: 3.3.0